# How to nicely format header comments in C++ mode of emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs

Here the "header comments" refers to:

```
/* Program Name: Foo                */
/* Author:       Jane Doe           */
/* Date:         06/29/2014         */
/* Rev:          1.0                */
```

The tricky parts are:

1. Hard to align the ending `*/` in each line if to use <kbd>M-;</kbd>
2. If possible, I'd like to align the content after `:` in each line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with two invocations of [`align-regexp`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands#toc4), though it's a bit tricky to type:

```c
/* Program Name: Foo */
/* Author: Jane Doe */
/* Date: 06/29/2014 */
/* Rev: 1.0 */
```

Select the region you wish to modify, then do your first `align-regexp` with a prefix argument:

```c
C-u M-x align-regexp RET :\(\s-*\) RET RET RET n
```

This version of `align-regexp` uses a regular expression matching the colon character, followed by any amount of whitespace. Then we

- accept the default option of modifying capture group 1 (the whitespace),
- then the default of leaving at least one space when we adjust,
- then tell Emacs not to repeat for the whole line, as we don't need that feature.

This should leave you with

```c
/* Program Name: Foo */
/* Author:       Jane Doe */
/* Date:         06/29/2014 */
/* Rev:          1.0 */
```

Now, `C-x C-x` to swap point and mark, reselecting your text, and do another `align-regexp`. This one doesn't need a prefix argument:

```c
 M-x align-regexp RET \*/ RET
```

This version is much simpler. We provide a regular expression that matches the close comment indicator `*/`, escaping the asterisk.

And you should be done! The final result looks like this:

```c
/* Program Name: Foo        */
/* Author:       Jane Doe   */
/* Date:         06/29/2014 */
/* Rev:          1.0        */
```

**Edit:**

You should be able to write a function to automate this process. I'm no elisp expert, but this seems to do the trick:

```lisp
(defun my-align-c-comment-block ()
  (interactive)
  (when (use-region-p)
    (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) ":\\(\\s-*\\)")
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (align-regexp (region-beginning) (region-end) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\*/")))
```

Comment: Code works great. I will go through the regex part soon.