# How to align codes in emacs C++ mode to ";" or ","?

Tags: c++, emacs

As a test engineer, I often have some spaghetti code like below:

```
  int *const cpe = &n; assert(42 == *cpe);
  int *const cpf = &cn; assert(42 == *cpf);
  int *const cpg = pcn; assert(42 == *cpg);
  int *const cph = cpcn; assert(42 == *cph);
```

For aesthetics, I would like to align them in columns defined by "**;**", like below:

```
  int *const cpe = &n;   assert(42 == *cpe);
  int *const cpf = &cn;  assert(42 == *cpf);
  int *const cpg = pcn;  assert(42 == *cpg);
  int *const cph = cpcn; assert(42 == *cph);
```

Is there a way in emacs to do this? (I know <kbd>M-x align</kbd> but it is not doing a neat job like desired.)
Hopefully the method should also work with "," too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you can just align on `assert` while the region is active:

```
M-x align-regexp assert RET
```

In general, the answer here is similar to the first part of [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471086/how-to-nicely-format-header-comments-in-c-mode-of-emacs/24471370#24471370):

```
C-u M-x align-regexp RET ;\(\s-*\) RET RET RET n
```

will turn

```
  int *const cpe = &n; assert(42 == *cpe);
  int *const cpf = &cn; assert(42 == *cpf);
  int *const cpg = pcn; assert(42 == *cpg);
  int *const cph = cpcn; assert(42 == *cph);
```

into

```
  int *const cpe = &n;   assert(42 == *cpe);
  int *const cpf = &cn;  assert(42 == *cpf);
  int *const cpg = pcn;  assert(42 == *cpg);
  int *const cph = cpcn; assert(42 == *cph);
```

The same technique can be used to align on commas. Just replace the `;` in the regular expression with `,`.

Comment: Seems to be a good universal technique. allow me a little time to play with and verify it .

Comment: @user3701346, it's easiest to use when you want to adjust whitespace *before* the thing you're matching, e.g. in this case with `assert`. It's trickier when you want to adjust whitespace *after*, like the general solution above, matching on `;`. That's simply because the default interactive behaviour of `align-regexp` automatically considers whitespace preceding your pattern as the thing to modify.

Answer (score 5):

```
(add-to-list 'align-rules-list
             '(c-assignment1
               (regexp . "[=;]\\(\\s-*\\)")
               (mode   . '(c-mode))
               (repeat . t)))
```

Simply `M-x align` works too, if you write this code.

Comment: Nice solution, I've never customized `align-rules-list` before.